# Add a door to a basement load bearing wall

Tags: load-bearing, footings

I am finishing my basement in a 1960 home, and a doorway is in an awkward place. I want to add an additional 36” doorway in a load-bearing wall that sits atop a ridge footing that is 5” above the  slab.

Obviously I will need to remove a section of that footing, level to the floor.  What is the appropriate way to get rid of that section of raised footing? Also, the ceiling is 7’ and the existing headers in existing doorways in this wall consist of two 2x4s stacked on one another.

I assume that is not appropriate, but probably for headroom.

**EDIT:** (*Information from the OP that was erroneously posted in the answer field*).

It’s inside, and it is the middle wall and I want to move an interior doorway. I would have to step over the raised concrete ridge and want to take out the unused portion after I install a doorway (*using header and jack studs*)

Comment: you need pictures and a diagram.   Are you saying this wall is completely exposed to the outside already?

Comment: This is not really a DIY question. Footing modifications and load bearing calculations require qualified engineering.

Comment: Blee, i added the info that you posted in the answer field, into the question. Please take the tour so you know how to participate here. https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour